# AngularJS and TypeScript - defining a service to be used in a controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-routing

I can't make this thing to work, it is super stressing and confusing.

I want to define an Angular service and use it in an Angular controller. The service knows if the user is logged in and the controller redirects the user to the login page if he's not.

**mainservice.ts**

```
/// <reference path="assets/angular.d.ts"/>

module OdgApp
 {
    export class MyMainService  
    {
        constructor() 
        {
            console.log("MyMainService constructor");
            this.autenticato = false;
        }

        public Autenticato():boolean 
        {
            return this.autenticato;
        }

        public SetAutenticato(nuovoValore:boolean):void 
        {
            this.autenticato = nuovoValore;
        }

        private autenticato: boolean;
    }

    angular
        .module("OdgApp")
        .service("MyMainService", MyMainService);
}
```

First question, do the module name have to be the same as the Angular module name? This is confusing. I've called both `OdgApp`.

Then I want to use the service in the login controller:

**loginctrl.ts**

```
/// <reference path="assets/angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="mymainservice.ts"/>  //IS THIS REQUIRED??

//import ms = require("mymainservice.OdgApp"); //IS THIS REQUIRED?


module OdgApp
{
    'use strict';
   //export interface IController {} //IS THIS REQUIRED?


    export class LoginCtrl  //DO I HAVE TO implement IController?
    {
        static $inject = ['$location', 'MyMainService'];  

        constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService, private servizio: MyMainService)  
        {
            console.log("LoginCtrl constructor");
            this.erroreLogin = false;
        }

        public utentePasswordVuoti() : boolean
        {
            if ( ! (this.utente && this.password) )
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public faiLogin() : boolean
        {
            console.log("utente: " + this.utente);
            console.log("passwd: " + this.password);

            //TODO: call http service to check for authentication 
            if ( true ) //  simulation
            {
                this.erroreLogin = false;

                this.servizio.SetAutenticato(true);

                this.$location.path('/home');
            }

            return true;
        }


        private utente: string;
        private password: string;
        private erroreLogin: boolean;
    }

    angular
        .module("OdgApp")
        .controller("LoginCtrl", LoginCtrl); 
}
```

The main module is in **app.ts**:

```
/// <reference path="assets/angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="assets/angular-route.d.ts"/>

module OdgApp // the same as Angular module? 
{
    'use strict';

    var main = angular.module("OdgApp", 
        [
            "ngRoute", 
            "LoginCtrl",
            "MyMainService" // Do I need to reference this here?
        ]);


    routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"];

    function routeConfig($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider): void
    {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/login", 
            {
                templateUrl: "/login.html",
                controller: "LoginCtrl as vm"
            })
            .when("/home", 
            {
                templateUrl: "/home.html",
                controller: "LoginCtrl as vm"
            })
            .otherwise(
            {
                redirectTo: "/login"
            });
    }

    main.config(routeConfig);
}
```

And the three html files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="OdgApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Ordine Del Giorno</title>

        <link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />     
        <link href="assets/odg.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="assets/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/mymainservice.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/loginctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="javascripts/mainctrl.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>

</html>
```

**login.html**

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as vm">
    LOGIN
</div>  <!-- /container -->
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as login" >
    HOME PAGE
</div>  <!-- /container -->
```

It all compiles but running it gives me the following errors:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module OdgApp due
>   to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module LoginCtrl
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'LoginCtrl' is not available!
>   You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
>   registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the
>   second argument.

I need to be pointed in the right direction, this is all confusing!

Here's a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/DW2AOXeytfFA76xFvbFx?p=info

Comment: No... ,you can give any name (type script module name)

Comment: did you convert ts to js ?,in plunker only ts not any js